# How to pass variables via $.ajax to a controller

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, joomla-api, ajax

I found some portions of codes but I don't know how to complete it. I need to pass some variables via ajax to controller in order to store them in Joomla session. So I have the code:

```
<input type="text" name="id" value="2" />

$('.add').click(function() {
 $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "index.php?option=com_mycom&task=add&format=raw",
  data: {id:1},
  dataType: 'json'
 }).done(function() {
   alert("Data Saved");
  });
 return false;
});
```

and the code in controller:

```
public function add() {
    $session = JFactory::getSession();
    $value = ???
    $cart = array();
    $cart['item'] = array('id' => $value);
    $session->set('cart', $cart);
}
```

As you see I don't know how to get data in the controller (and I'm not sure that I send it properly in $.ajax). And do I really need json in my case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use Joomla's JInput class https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

e.g.

```
public function add() {

  // Get Joomla's input object:
  $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

  // Get the variable
  $value = $input->get('id');

  $session = JFactory::getSession();
  $cart = array();
  $cart['item'] = array('id' => $value);
  $session->set('cart', $cart);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you want to use the input.

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;    
$value = $input->get('id');
```

Comment: Thanks Lodder, I was posting from my phone and didn't get the styling right.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$value = $_POST['id'];
```

That's like the easy approach, might not be best practice any more though. I would recommend this for testing purposes only, it delivers fast results but is not really safe. For that I recommend looking into the JInput class as mentioned by the other answer.

As for the JSON question, I just found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it) which has some answers explaining it quite well I guess.

Comment: Okay... I am willing to delete my answer if somebody could explain me why they keep downvoting me. To my experience, this works, and I just answered the question. Thanks!

Comment: theres not input filtering - so you are opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks if you then used $value inside a database query.
For example someone could post :
 id = "');delete * from table;".

 And if you didn't sanitize the input and wrote a query $query->update('table')->set('foo = "' . $value . '"'); 
your query would be written out as :
update table set foo = "');delete * from table;"

Comment: @Rob, yes, I know that - that's why I put "for testing purposes" ;-) thanks for your reply though.